# How to set the locale with symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, locale, symfony-3.4

How can I change the locale using symfony 3.4 (php)?

I have the locale saved for each user in my database. Now on [this page](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/translation/locale.html) they explain that you should create an event listener to set the locale. But they only provide a method - in which class do I put this method and how do I wire it up using my services.yml?

And if I'm in the service - how can I access my user object to actually get the locale I want to set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an [example provided by the docs on how to create an kernel request listener](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/event_dispatcher.html#request-events-checking-types).

In this listener you inject the TokenStorage serivce, which then provides you the current token and with it the attached user that is currently logged in. Then you take the locale from the user and set it to the request.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class RequestListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $request->setLocale($user->getLocale());
    }  
}
```

To understand, why Symfony requires the type-hint of an interface instead of an class [please read the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces).

Comment: Using your code I get the error message: Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener": argument "$tokenStorage" of method "__construct()" references class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage" but no such service exists. Try changing the type-hint to "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface" instead. But with TokenStorageInterface, I can't access the user ... any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. May I ask you to make an example?

Comment: The solution suggessted doesn't work for me yet, so I can't accept it as an answer yet. If I change `TokenStorage` to `TokenStorageInterface`, the method `getToken()` expects an argument and I don't know which argument I should set here.

Comment: I was using `\Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\TokenStorageInterface` instead, that was the problem. Thanks for providing the correct interface - stupid error on my side. Thank you for your patience in helping me with this problem. It is working now.

Comment: @MathiasBader okay, i see, that's something different indeed. Glad that i could help you.