# How to set the locale on a request using symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, localization, locale, symfony-3.4

I am using symfony 3.4 and I want to set the display locale for a request.

I tried as explained [in the Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/translation/locale.html) with the following code

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class EventListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $request->setLocale('en');
    }
}
```

but it doesn't affect the page. On the symfony status bar it still shows me `de_DE` as locale. I read the explanation on this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905684/how-to-set-the-locale-with-symfony-3-4), but I feel like I did exactly what is described there. So what did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom listener must be called before LocaleListener, which initializes the locale based on the current request. To do so, set your listener priority to a higher value than LocaleListener priority (which you can obtain running the debug:event kernel.request command).
check the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/translation/locale.html

Comment: That works. It surprises me, because I was setting in the same EventListener the locale of the user (when logged in) and that worked. So how did that work then?

Comment: in your case u needed to overide the LocaleListener with your custom one, setting your custom listener priority higher than LocaleListener will force it to change the locale